# Freezed - the getter 'x' isn't defined for x

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

I'm trying to get started with Freezed, and I define this class below, and the rest of my app doesn't seem to pick up that it has an `id` property:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'user.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class VpUser implements _$VpUser {
  factory VpUser({String id, User firebaseUser}) = _VpUser;
  const factory VpUser.empty() = _Empty;
  const VpUser._();
}
```

I use the class in my authentication service:

```
class AuthenticationService extends VpService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Rx<User> _firebaseUser = Rx<User>();
  VpUser get user =>
      VpUser(id: _firebaseUser.value?.uid, firebaseUser: _firebaseUser.value);
```

then I call the user attached to the AuthService like so:

```
if (_authenticationService.user.id != null) {
```

And I have the error:

> Error: The getter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'VpUser'.
>
> - 'VpUser' is from 'package:vepo/domain/auth/user.dart' ('lib/domain/auth/user.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of
>   an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.
>   if (_authenticationService.user.id != null) {

How do I declare the id in `VpUser` so other classes can access it?

Answer (score 0):

It must have been my `VpUser.empty` implementation, not declaring the `id` field.

I think this is how to do an empty value without making the rest of the app not see the property:

```
const factory VpUser.empty(
  {@nullable @Default(null) String id,
  @nullable @Default(null) User firebaseUser}) = _Empty;
```